# Double Buffering and Viewport Origin?

Tags: c++, gdi, win32gui

I wanted to put the origin in the centre so I did:

```
SetViewportOrgEx(hdc,width/2,height/2,NULL);
```

(as seen in the code below)

Now, after implementing double buffering it doesn't seem to work properly. Any ideas why and what should be best practice here? Many Thanks

Code Below:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            int width=rect.right;
            int height=rect.bottom;

                    //Changing Origin position
            SetViewportOrgEx(hdc,width/2,height/2,NULL);


            HDC backbuffDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

            HBITMAP backbuffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, width, height);

            int savedDC = SaveDC(backbuffDC);
            SelectObject( backbuffDC, backbuffer );
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
            FillRect(backbuffDC,&rect,hBrush);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);

                    //Drawing on backbuffDC


            BitBlt(hdc,0,0,width,height,backbuffDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
            RestoreDC(backbuffDC,savedDC);
            DeleteObject(backbuffer);
            DeleteDC(backbuffDC);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `BitBlt` is trying to blit from the centre to somewhere off screen. Make sure you do error checking and ensure everything succeeds when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you changed the viewport origin, you must ensure that the coordinates are updated accordingly. In the case of `BitBlt`, you are now passing `(width/2, height/2)` as the upper left corner, `width` as the width, and `height` as the height. This results in a blit to an area that is half off of your device context, which should end up causing the portion that is within the destination device context to be displayed as such, and the rest clipped.

To fix it, change the coordinates:

```
BitBlt(hdc,-width/2,-height/2,width,height,backbuffDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
```

Secondly, I'm not sure about this one myself, but make sure valid coordinates are being passed to `FillRect`. What you're passing retrieved coordinates independent to the device context and its viewport, so those might have to be transformed as well.

Comment: Here is an image to show what's going on:

http://i48.tinypic.com/k1sz20.jpg

Doing so, has shifted it to default behaviour i.e. origin in the top left corner. I am coloring red with FillRect now so you can see how it is working.

Comment: @user1788175, Do you have one of before the change handy? It looks as if it's using (0,0) as the centre of the backbuffer dc, which hasn't had its viewport changed, or perhaps `BitBlt` treats all coordinates as if they were of the destination DC. I haven't changed the coordinate system, so I have no experiences to go off of.